# How to display an image from a json url on the internet

Tags: c#, macos, xamarin

new xamarin programmer here. I need to display a comic image from the internet using a URL but somehow, the system keeps telling me that the link to the url does not work but I don't know why when I instantiate a new UriImageSource.

My first method was to try displaying the image using **BitMapImage** but it is only available for WindowsForms or WPF so I need an alternative for that as well if UriImageSource does not work for me. I'm on a Mac btw.

This is the xaml:

```
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="Weather_App.MainPage"> 
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="auto" />
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <StackLayout Grid.Row="1" Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalOptions="Center">
            <Image x:Name="backgroundImage" Margin="20"/>

        </StackLayout>
    </Grid>
</ContentPage>
```

This is the MainPage.cs:

```
using Xamarin.Forms;

namespace Weather_App
{
    // Learn more about making custom code visible in the Xamarin.Forms previewer
    // by visiting https://aka.ms/xamarinforms-previewer
    [DesignTimeVisible(false)]
    public partial class MainPage : ContentPage 
    {
        private int maxNumber = 0;
        private int currentNumber = 0;

        public MainPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            ViewModel.ApiHelper.InitializeClient();

            string url = Convert.ToString(ComicProcessor.LoadComic());
            backgroundImage.Source = new UriImageSource
            {
                Uri = new Uri(url),
                CachingEnabled = false,
                CacheValidity = TimeSpan.FromHours(1)
            };

        }
    }
}
```

Finally, this is the viewmodel/LoadComic method. I tried to return the comic at first instead of the url but since the BitMapImage didn't exist for Mac, I returned the **url instead** because I thought I could have used it for the UriImageSource instance. The comic properties include an integer Num and a string Img.

```
namespace Weather_App
{
    public class ComicProcessor
    {
        public static int MaxComicNumber { get; set; }
        public async static Task<string> LoadComic(int comicNumber = 0)
        {
            string url = "";
            if (comicNumber > 0)
            {
                url = $"https://xkcd.com/{comicNumber}/info.0.json";
            }
            else
            {
                url = $"https://xkcd.com/info.0.json";
            }

            using (HttpResponseMessage response = await ViewModel.ApiHelper.ApiClient.GetAsync(url))
            {
                if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)//If response successful do something then
                {
                    // Takes data in as json and converted it to the type you have given and match anything that it finds 
                    ComicModel comic = await response.Content.ReadAsAsync<ComicModel>();

                    if (comicNumber == 0)
                    {
                        MaxComicNumber = comic.Num;
                    }

                    return url;
                }
                else
                {
                    // Outputs reason why it wasn't successful
                    throw new Exception(response.ReasonPhrase);
                }

            }


        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest you use [FFImageLoading's](https://github.com/luberda-molinet/FFImageLoading#ffimageloading---fast--furious-image-loading) CachedImage for this.

It is a library that is vastly accepted by the community and is great with caching and has memory handling options as well.

You can check their [Git wiki](https://github.com/luberda-molinet/FFImageLoading/wiki) to understand the library in depth.

Download it form [Nuget](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Xamarin.FFImageLoading/)

Call `CachedImageRenderer.Init()` on each platform. Let’s put it on `MainActivity.cs` of our Android project and `AppDelegate.cs` of iOS.

Then add its namespace and use it like this:

```
  <ffimageloading:CachedImage
                HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="Center"
                DownsampleToViewSize="true"
                Source = "{Binding ImageUrl}">
        </ffimageloading:CachedImage>
```

`Xamarin.Forms.Image` is an option but I personally feel it doesn't work well with URL images.

Also just give CachedImage the URL and it will do the downloading for you!

Goodluck,

Feel free to get back if you have questions.